# how to get particular data from the file using the python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to extract some particular data from the file and use that data into the script. Could you please help me how to do this?

Example:
filename - information.txt

```
Application_Name - 'Text Miner'
     output_file - medaff_text_miner.csv
     s3_location - itx-ags-medaff-prd-sourcefiles/Refined_Layer/
     delimiter - '|'
     input_query - medaff_text_miner_query.txt

Application_Name - 'Text Extraction'
     output_file - medaff_text_extraction.csv
     s3_location - itx-ags-medaff-prd-sourcefiles/Refined_Layer/
     delimiter - ','
     input_file - medaff_text_extraction_query.txt
```

I have python script in which I need to use above information. In argument I am passing passing application_name. So based on the application name it should to select corresponding information from the file and use into the script. Could you please help me how to do this?

Python script which I am using:

```
def generate_Canada_Event_metadata_file():
    try:
        logging.info("Generating the File............[started]")
        conn = redshift_conn()

        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            path = input_path + input_query

            sql_file = open(path, 'r')
            sql_query = sql_file.read()
            print(sql_query)
            cur.execute(sql_query)
            result = cur.fetchall()
            #print(result)
            conn.commit()
            column = [i[0] for i in cur.description]

            df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns= column)
            os.system('rm -f '+ ec2_output + 'Canada_Event.csv')
            df.to_csv(ec2_output + output_file, index= False, sep =delimiter)
            os.system('chmod 777 '+ ec2_output + 'Canada_Event.csv')
            logging.info("Generating the Canada_Event File............[Ended]")
            s3_copy()
    except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            logging.info("Generating the Canada_Event File............[ERROR]")
            logging.error(ex)
            sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: is the .txt file exactly formatted as given in the example?

Comment: @CoolCloud no .. I just tell you what will be the content of text file.

Comment: oh okays, i see

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but you can try something like this:

```
def parse_applications_infos(filepath):
    apps = {}
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if 'Application_Name' not in line:
                app_info.append(line)
            else:
                if len(app_info) != 0:
                     apps[line.rsplit('-').strip()[-1]] = (read_stats(app_info))
     return apps

def read_stats(application_info):
    info = {}
    for line in application_info:
        key, value = application_info.split('-').strip()
        info[key] = value
        return info

application_data = parse_applications_info('C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Apps.txt')

for k, v in application_data['Text Miner'].iteritems():
    # do something with the flag/arg and value
    my_cmds.append(f"{k} {v}")
```

What it's doing is looking for the delimiter "Application_Name", and then creating a dict with the application names as the keys, and dicts as values with each of the arguments/flag and values as that dict's kv's.